# Direct map vs fully associative

Tags: caching

The benefits of each technique are well known to me.

but I wonder if there is a case when direct map can yield better hit rate over the data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of entries is the same, and the replacement policy is the same, then direct mapped, provably, can at best be the same, never better (assuming a uniform distribution of addresses -- pathological sequences aside).

The place where direct mapped *might* be better is when you do something like say "okay, here is my power budget, which version gives the best hit rate for that power?".  Or, if you say "here is my cycle time, which type gives better performance?"

Direct mapped is lower power than fully associative (everything else, like capacity, being the same), so you could conceivably get much larger capacity with direct mapped for the same power, and at the same cycle time, and thereby get a better hit rate.

Also, direct mapped is higher speed than fully associative for certain implementations, everything else being equal (such as same number of entries).  The speed of ASIC memories degrades relatively slowly with capacity, so you could conceivably get a much much larger capacity of direct mapped at the same cycle time, and thereby get better hit rate and so better overall performance.

Or, if cache speed is the limiter of overall clock (which is often the case), then you could keep the capacity the same and let the faster clock give more instr/sec.  That performance gain, due to faster clock, may overcome the loss in performance due to worse hit rate.

You have to do the experiments, with the given process technology, and given workload, and see.